# SQLiteを使用して、テーブルに番号を高速で振る方法

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

お世話になります。

データベースはSQLite限定で、ある特定の2000件ほどのテーブルがあるとし、
これにランダムで番号を順に振っていく、『高速でできる』方法を探しています。

id,name,price,index
1,りんご,300,0
2,いちご、150,0
3,すもも,250,0
.
.
.
2000,ぶどう,470,0

上記のようなテーブルがあるとし、一番後ろのデータ(indexのところ)に
1から2000の重複しないユニークなデータを振りたいと思っています。

このようなことは、SQLだけで実現は可能でしょうか。そして、肝心なのは
高速でできるか、ということです。

現在の私の知識では解らないので、コードと併用して下記のように行っています。

1,データをSELECTで ORDER BYRANDOM()で一覧を配列として取得
2,コード上でforで回しながら、配列の順番にindexをUPDATEする(UPDATE xxx SET index = i WHERE id = 配列n番目のid)
3,indexをインクリメントする(i++)
4,2のforを配列の要素数分繰り返す

順序立てて行えば、このパターンで実行できますが、SQL単体で完結しない上に
動作が遅いです。2000行処理するのに1分ほどかかってしまいます。
勿論、PCのスペックなども影響はしますが、行数が多い状態で一行毎UPDATEするのが
時間がかかっていると思います。

これを高速で、できるならばSQLだけで実現することはできますでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 相関サブクエリを使った方法を回答していたのですがよく考えるとどうもうまくいきません。申し訳ありませんが一旦削除しました。

Answer (score 8):

きちんとトランザクションを管理していますか？
SQLiteはデフォルトでは一件更新毎にコミットが走るため、遅いです。

2000件程度ならば一気に`select`したものを一回のトランザクションで済ませれば質問者さんのロジックで5秒もかかりません。
言語の指定がないのでPythonで書くならこんな感じです。

```py
connection = sqlite3.connect(DBファイル, isolation_level='EXCLUSIVE')

# selectしてリスト化

connection.execute('BEGIN IMMEDIATE')
connection.executemany(insert文, タプルのリスト(全件分)) # または一件ずつinsert
connection.commit()
```

言語はC#とのことですので、未検証ですが、C#だと以下のような感じで良いと思います。

```cs
public static void execSQL(string SQL)
{
    using (SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(DATABASE_PATH))
    {
        cnn.Open();
        using (SQLiteTransaction trans = con.BeginTransaction())
        {
            using (SQLiteCommand cmd = cnn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = SQL;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            trans.Commit();
        }
        cnn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: 回答、ありがとうございます。
初心者なもので、トランザクションを云々というのは、一切行っておりませんでした。

ちなみに、私はC#にて記述しています。
本来なら、質問時に記述すべきでした。申し訳ありません。

//  値のクリア
DB.execSQL("UPDATE list SET index = 0");
string[] stList = SELECTでランダムに並び替えて抽出したリスト(list)の一部;
int iIndex = 1;
foreach (string s in stList)
{
    string ss = s.Replace("'", "''");
    DB.execSQL("UPDATE list SET index = " + iIndex + " WHERE name = '" + ss + "'");
     iIndex++;
}

DB.exevSQLは、ＳＱLiteにSQLを投げているメソッドです。

このような感じなのですが、内容に問題ありますでしょうか。
ご指導をお願いいたします。

Comment: @たたぱた C#でのトランザクション処理を追加しました。

Comment: 何度も回答をいただき、ありがとうございます。
大変申し訳ないのですが、BeginTransactionとEndTrassactionは
どのクラスから呼び出すのでしょうか。
今のコードでは、このようになっています。
        public static void execSQL(string SQL)
        {
            using (SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(DATABASE_PATH))
            using (SQLiteCommand cmd = cnn.CreateCommand())
            {

                cnn.Open();

                cmd.CommandText = SQL;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                cnn.Close();
            }
        }

上記のSQLiteConnectionのcnnで呼び出すのでしょうか。この中には、
Beginはありましたが、Endが出てきませんでした。
鞭で申し訳ありませんが、何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: @たたぱた なんの技術を使用してSQLiteを使用しているかの記載がなく、こちらとしてはトランザクション処理を行ってくださいとしか言えないのですが･･･`System.Data.SQLite`を使っているのですか？一応それらしい記述にしていますが、未検証です。

Comment: @たたぱた こちらも参考にどうぞ。http://uniunix.com/blog/?p=154

Comment: すみません。使用しているのは、ご指摘の通り、System.Da‌​ta.SQLiteです。
参考URL、ありがとうございます。拝見させていただいてます。

Answer (score 4):

どうしても SQL だけでということなら、

```
create table tbl_new (
  id integer,
  name text,
  price integer,
  idx integer primary key autoincrement
);
insert into tbl_new (id, name, price) select id, name, price from tbl_test;
alter table tbl_test rename to tbl_old;
alter table tbl_new rename to tbl_test;
```

という方法もあります。カラムの型が若干変わってしまいますが。
手元では1秒かからず一瞬で完了しました。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
SQL単体で何とかできるということは希望が持てますが、
すみません。初心者なもので、どのようなことを行っているのかが
解りません。

お教えいただきましたこの方法では、データの項目数が増えても
速度的な違いはありませんでしょぅか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 項目数とは行数のことでしょうか。100万件で試しましたが1秒かかりませんでした。速度的には問題ないと思います。

Comment: 何度も恐れ入ります。
項目数はカラム、のことです。サンプルでは4カラムでしたが、
実際は12,3カラムのデータです。
また、これも今更記述すべきことではないのですが、idはオートナンバーの
データのため、走査することはできません。大変申し訳ありません。

ただし、ランダムに振る数値ですが、ユニークであり大小関係さえわかれば、
1からじゅんでなく、427などから始まっても、6の次が7でなく、300になっても
構いません。　　すみません、始めから明確にするべきでした。

Answer (score 1):

参考までに INTEGER PRIMARY KEY　AUTOINCREMENT
http://www.dbonline.jp/sqlite/table/index9.html

Comment: 趣旨が違ったようですね・・・申し訳ないｍｍ

Answer (score 1):

> ユニークであり大小関係さえわかれば、 1からじゅんでなく、427などから始まっても、6の次が7でなく、300になっても 構いません。

この条件でいいのでしたら、ランダムな数に「idの最大値 + 1」を掛けて、「idの値」を足せば、ユニークになることが保証されると思います。

そしてSQLだけで更新できます。

```sql
UPDATE table SET index = ((abs(random()) % 100000) * 2001) + id;
```